# Add fadein/out to onscroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help me to add a proper fadeIn fadeOut to the following code? There is something that I'm missing. I'm using this onscroll to take a div on top of the page and use it as a fix menu while scrolling.

```
<script>
var windowWidth = $(window ).width();
if(windowWidth>1580){
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.onscroll = function() { 
        if (window.pageYOffset >= 1400){
            $(".main2").css({position: "fixed", left: "0", top:"20px", background:"white"});
            $(".main2").css({"width":"290"});
            $(".main2").css({"min-height":"300"});
            $(".main2").css({"max-height":"600"});
            $(".main2").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
            $(".main2").css("zIndex", "9999");
            $(".main2").css("font-size", "9");
            $(".immagine1").css("display","none");
            $(".share").css({position: "fixed", right: "0", top: "20px", background:"white"});
            $(".share").css({"width":"120"});
            $(".share").css({"height":"100"});

        }
        else {
            $(".main2").css({position: "", right: "", top: "", background:""});
            $(".main2").css({"width":""});
            $(".main2").css({"min-height":""});
            $(".main2").css({"max-height":""});
            $(".main2").css({"overflow":""});
            $(".main2").css("zIndex", "");
            $(".main2").css("font-size", "");
            $(".immagine1").css("display","");
            $(".share").css({position: "", right: "", top: "", background:""});
            $(".share").css({"width":""});
            $(".share").css({"height":""});
        }
    }
})};
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking!

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle showing javascript and csss and the elements and explain the problem in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a plugin for this.

I‘m using [Wow](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)